# Getting error while running Maven Project from Jenkins even though same setup works on Locally

Tags: java, selenium

Description : Same POM works locally with same suit but when i am swtiching to Jenkins execution, it shows the errors. Can anyone please help me to understand why this may happening?

Error Message recevied while running job from jenkins :

```
    Started by user unknown or anonymous
    [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
    Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite
     > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
    Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
     > git config remote.origin.url git@github.com:orionhcs/automation-tests.git # timeout=10
    Fetching upstream changes from git@github.com:orionhcs/automation-tests.git
     > git --version # timeout=10
    using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
     > git fetch --tags --progress git@github.com:orionhcs/automation-tests.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
     > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
     > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
    Checking out Revision 53f5d799bb2578706e48d80e1f428ca5a324e96c (refs/remotes/origin/master)
     > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
     > git checkout -f 53f5d799bb2578706e48d80e1f428ca5a324e96c
    Commit message: "updated the code"
     > git rev-list --no-walk 53f5d799bb2578706e48d80e1f428ca5a324e96c # timeout=10
    [WanderlyAutomationSuite] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins8894762653318384960.sh
    + export M2_HOME=/srv/maven/
    Parsing POMs
    Established TCP socket on 37493
    [WanderlyAutomationSuite] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64//bin/java -cp /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-1.12.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.4/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.4/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main /var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.tasks.Maven_MavenInstallation/Maven_3.5.4 /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-3.19.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-interceptor-1.12.jar /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.12.jar 37493
    <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
    Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite/pom.xml compile test
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] ---------------------< Wanderly:WanderlyScenarios >---------------------
    [INFO] Building WanderlyScenarios 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite/src/main/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite/src/main/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite/src/test/resources
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
    [INFO] No sources to compile
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
    [INFO] No tests to run.
    [INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite/target/surefire-reports

    -------------------------------------------------------
     T E S T S
    -------------------------------------------------------
    Running TestSuite

    Results :

    Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

    [JENKINS] Recording test results
    hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did leafNodes run? 
    For example, /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite/target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml is 37 min old

        at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:266)
        at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:231)
        at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:148)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:629)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoFailed(Maven3Builder.java:662)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy.onEvent(Maven3Builder.java:306)
        at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.onEvent(EventSpyDispatcher.java:104)
        at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyExecutionListener.mojoFailed(EventSpyExecutionListener.java:138)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:220)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
        at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main(Maven35Launcher.java:130)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch(Maven35Main.java:176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
        at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
        at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
        at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 5.440 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-06T12:25:02-08:00
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project WanderlyScenarios: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
    [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
    [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.scenarios.Wanderly_ApplyJob_Scenario
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:546)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    [ERROR] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    [ERROR] at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:300)
    [ERROR] at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1021)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
    [ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
    [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
    [JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/WanderlyAutomationSuite/pom.xml to Wanderly/WanderlyScenarios/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/WanderlyScenarios-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
    channel stopped
    Finished: FAILURE
```

Below is the POM file which has created to run the script : 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        4.0.0

```
    <groupId>Wanderly</groupId>
    <artifactId>WanderlyScenarios</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WanderlyScenarios</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>testngExecutor.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>

                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>

                </configuration>


            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.9</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.46.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.17</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.qmetry/qaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.qmetry</groupId>
            <artifactId>qaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.14-RC2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>




    After using "**mvn clean install**" shows below error : 
        it seems the error is related with maven with surefire plugin:
Can you please help me on this?
            [INFO] Scanning for projects...
            [INFO]
            [INFO] ---------------------< Wanderly:WanderlyScenarios >---------------------
            [INFO] Building WanderlyScenarios 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
            [INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom (3.9 kB at 1.5 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom (13 kB at 24 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.jar (25 kB at 38 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.pom (5.8 kB at 11 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.jar
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/2.4/maven-jar-plugin-2.4.jar (34 kB at 44 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom (6.4 kB at 15 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar (27 kB at 48 kB/s)
            [INFO]
            [INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.pom
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.pom (4.1 kB at 10 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/spice/spice-parent/16/spice-parent-16.pom
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/spice/spice-parent/16/spice-parent-16.pom (8.4 kB at 19 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/forge/forge-parent/5/forge-parent-5.pom
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/sonatype/forge/forge-parent/5/forge-parent-5.pom (8.4 kB at 19 kB/s)
            Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
            Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar (226 kB at 181 kB/s)
            [INFO] Deleting E:\Study Material\Selenium\WanderlyScenarios - NormalFW\target
            [INFO]
            [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
            [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
            [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\Study Material\Selenium\WanderlyScenarios - NormalFW\src\main\resources
            [INFO]
            [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
            [INFO] No sources to compile
            [INFO]
            [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
            [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
            [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory E:\Study Material\Selenium\WanderlyScenarios - NormalFW\src\test\resources
            [INFO]
            [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
            [INFO] No sources to compile
            [INFO]
            [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ WanderlyScenarios ---
            [INFO] No tests to run.
            [INFO] Surefire report directory: E:\Study Material\Selenium\WanderlyScenarios - NormalFW\target\surefire-reports
            -------------------------------------------------------
             T E S T S
            -------------------------------------------------------
            Running TestSuite
            Results :
            Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            [INFO] Total time: 01:11 min
            [INFO] Finished at: 2019-03-07T11:16:08+05:30
            [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project WanderlyScenarios: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
            [ERROR] org.testng.TestNGException:
            [ERROR] Cannot find class in classpath: com.scenarios.Wanderly_ApplyJob_Scenario
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.loadClass(XmlClass.java:81)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.init(XmlClass.java:73)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.XmlClass.<init>(XmlClass.java:59)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.TestNGContentHandler.startElement(TestNGContentHandler.java:546)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:182)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1339)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2784)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
            [ERROR]         at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
            [ERROR]         at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:38)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:172)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:300)
            [ERROR]         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1021)
            [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
            [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
            [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
            [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
            [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
            [ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
            [ERROR]
            [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
            [ERROR]
            [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
            [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
            [ERROR]
            [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
            [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

            Even when I am using "mvn compile test", its working for me locally. Even when I am trying to run inside eclispe then also it works properly*
```

Comment: Try running once on your machine locally `mvn clean install` and **don't** skip the tests. It seems the error - `Cannot find class in classpath: com.scenarios.Wanderly_ApplyJob_Scenario` is a XML parse error and it could not find the required class in classpath.

Comment: I added new error in below the POM code section. Can you please check it? I am deleting ".m2" folder and running "mvn compile test", its working fine then.

Comment: What maven version you're using and what version is with jenkins?

Comment: Jenkins 2.117, Maven 3.5.4